# How to pass parameter from javascript to Ajax function

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I need help on this, I have this code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removerow('.$row["sn"].');">
     <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color: red"></i>
</a>
```

and i need to get value from `onclick="removerow('.$row["sn"].')` to this function

```
function removerow() 
{
    var vpb_sn = _______.val();
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as "php"?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it looks very much to me that this HTML is part of some PHP code that is missing the larger context. Note the variable prefaced with `$`, and the real giveaway is the `.`s which looks very much like concatenation of PHP strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass value:

```
onclick="removerow('.$row["sn"].');"
```

Accept it:

```
function removerow(value) 
{
    // and you can use it just like variable
    console.log(value);
}
```

Sends var to php file (using jquery ajax):

```
function removerow(value) 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php', // here path to php file
        type: 'post',  //type of a query
        data: {myVariable: value}, // data which sends into php file
        success: function (data) {
            alert('sended successfully!');
        }
    });
}
```

And then, inside index.php (file, on which data was sended), we can saw our data using this:

```
$_POST['myVariable'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer let me try and i will come back

Comment: But how to declare as a variable so I can be able to pass to PHP file?

Comment: @JamesTigwela Added to answer